# Organising function apps to deploy from azure devops - pipelines CI/CD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I’m looking into what is the best approach to deploying function apps via azure devops pipelines. I have a solution that contains 4 function apps. My first thought when creating the pipeline > release pipeline is that if one function app changes then all functions are then deployed. I don’t really want that. So my thoughts turn to splitting up all function apps into separate solutions to then have separate branches. That would stop all function apps being deployed.

My question is; is it possible to create yaml for the pipeline to just build certain projects and to then deploy certain projects?

That way I wouldn’t have to split out the function app projects out. But is that best or bad practice when organising function apps to then use CI/CD devop pipelines?

Any thoughts / best practices / experiences / advice would be good. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple pipeline files if you want to independently manage the functions. You can use something like below to determine what changes to certain projects will trigger each pipeline. Here's an example from one of my pipeline files.

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - feature/*
    - release/*
    - develop
  paths:
    include:
    - Project1
    - CommonFolder1
    - CommonFolder2
    - CommonFolderWildcardsWorkToo*
    - pipeline-file.yaml
    exclude:
    - You can also use the exclude path if that's easier
```

This is exactly how I handle this.

The other option is to have a single function app and then just have your functions in one function app.

Comment: Derek Williams. So pipeline-file.yaml that you reference is the contents that you have used that includes the trigger through to paths. I assume you then do the usual build, publish artifacts as part of the yaml script? Before you then create the release pipeline

Comment: Yes, the snippet file in this example is `pipeline-file.yaml`. It's included in the include block so that a build is triggered if I make changes to the pipeline file.

I don't use release pipelines. I use Multi-stage pipelines that are all defined with YAML. I use environments to put up manual gates, etc. However, if you use release pipelines, each file can publish it's artifact and be managed independently.

Comment: Now having an issue running tests;The below is not working; any advice please?

- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  inputs:
    packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
    versionSelector: 'latestStable'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    #testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory~TestCat1'
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'
    testAssemblyVer2: '*.Tests.dll'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: *.Tests.dll.

Comment: I'd attempt to use the wildcard search for your DLLs. It can be referenced by doing `**/*.Tests.dll`. Azure DevOps has wide support for RegEx searches.

Comment: @Dereck Williams Thanks for the help. I have managed to create 4 separate yml files that only build/ deploy specific projects only and to run tests by category only.